# Declare objects in every method?

Tags: java, object, methods

So I'm new to java, but I'm fluent in python, and I'm stuck on a basic problem. Do I have to declare an object in the same method in which I'm going to use it? Or is there a way to transfer objects from method to method? Thank you for your help (:

Comment: Do you mean `this`...?

Comment: suggest you read some basic java programming resources/books

Comment: I suggest you show a Python code that demonstrates the concept that you want to implement in Java. Chances are, someone fluent in both languages would come along, and show you how to translate the same concept to Java.

Comment: Please don't be mean.

Comment: I'll assume the answer is yes.

Comment: No one is being mean. The nature of the site is to downvote bad questions and upvote good questions. Bad questions are defined on the help page and your question just happens to be bad. [No one is immune from asking bad questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943855/site-structure-and-php-scripts)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: 'bad' doesn't mean it can't be fixed, or that you shouldn't be asking it however, you can fix it with editing. Highly suggest you follow dasblinenlight's advice: "I suggest you show a Python code that demonstrates the concept that you want to implement in Java. "

At the moment we don't know if you want to pass variables globally, via parameters, or if the methods should be declared on the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transfer objects from method to method is generally the most recommended way. This helps keep code modular and reduces coupling. A common concept in Java is getters and setters for custom classes. See example below:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String myString; // this variable can only be directly access from within MyClass scope.

    // constructor - called when an instance of MyClass is initialized ( e.g. MyClass myClass = new MyClass(); )
    public MyClass(){
        myString = "Hello world!"; // init my_string        
    }

    // Can access variable from within class to print
    public void printMyString(){
        System.out.println(myString);
    }

    // Can set private class variables
    public void setMyString(String input){
        this.myString = input; // set value
    }

    // Can get (return) private class variables
    public String getMyString(){
        return myString; // get value
    }
}
```

From another section in your program:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(); // init class (calls constructor)
System.out.println(myClass.getMyString()); // prints "Hello world!"
myClass.setMyString("Hola"); // changes value of myString
System.out.println(myClass.getMyString()); // prints "Hola"

System.out.println(myClass.myString); // Error: cannot directly access private variable of java class MyClass.
```

Answer (score -1):

Variables which should be available across multiple methods should be declared at the top of the class as follows.

```
public class Test{
  int number = 1;
  String text = "hello";

  public int method1() {
    return number + 1;
  }

  public String method2() {
    return text + " moo";
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you have another variable with the same name as one of the global variables you can refer to the global one with something like `this.number`